# R Conditional subtraction from the next unequal value

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a larger data frame with around 300k+ rows and 14 columns in the following form:

```
df <- data.frame(team_id = c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10),rep(4,10),rep(5,10)), 
             year = rep(c(1954:1963), 5), members= c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0),
            size = c(rep(60,8),50,50,rep(40,7),50,50,70,rep(30,10),rep(99,6),110,101,101,101,rep(80,9),66) )
```

The aim is to create a new vector containing the difference in size, for each team, once all members left (members change from 2 or 1 to 0) subtracting the size of the year of the last departure of players from the next different size.
The direction of change should be shown so absolute values are not necessary.
What I achieved so far is:

```
df2 <- df %>% arrange(team_id,year) %>%
          group_by(team_id)     %>%
          mutate(sizediff = if_else(members == 1  & lead(members) == 0 | members == 2  & lead(members) == 0,1,0, missing =  0) )
```

However, instead of the values 1 in the sizediff vector I want to have the difference to future size. Maybe changes from long to wide format or a conditional re-arrangement the year vector could help but I am stuck. What I want to achieve looks like:

```
aim <- data.frame(team_id = c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10),rep(4,10),rep(5,10)), 
             year = rep(c(1954:1963), 5), members= c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,    0,0,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,    0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0    ) ,
             size = c(57,rep(60,7),50,50,rep(40,7),50,50,70,rep(30,10),rep(99,6),110,101,101,101,88,rep(80,8),66), 
             sizediff = c(rep(0,6),-10,rep(0,3),rep(0,5),10,rep(0,4),rep(0,10),rep(0,3),11,rep(0,6),rep(0,7),-14,rep(0,2))    )
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to have the difference to future size.` ? Can you show the calculation for 1  `team_id` ?

Comment: Sure, so for team_id 1 from 1960 to 1961 the members change from 2 to 0. In 1960 the size was 60, in 1961 still 60 but in 1962 the size changes to 50. So I am looking for the value 50-60 = -10.    Thanks for your quick reaction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this custom approach :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(team_id) %>%
  mutate(sizediff = {
    sizediff = rep(0, n())
    inds <- which(members %in% c(1, 2)  & lead(members) == 0)[1]
    sizediff[inds] <- size[which(row_number() > inds & size != size[inds])[1]] - size[inds]
    sizediff
  }) -> result

result
#   team_id  year members  size sizediff
#     <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1       1  1954       0    60        0
# 2       1  1955       0    60        0
# 3       1  1956       0    60        0
# 4       1  1957       1    60        0
# 5       1  1958       1    60        0
# 6       1  1959       1    60        0
# 7       1  1960       2    60      -10
# 8       1  1961       0    60        0
# 9       1  1962       0    50        0
#10       1  1963       0    50        0
# … with 40 more rows
```

We first initialise `sizediff` to 0, `inds` is used to find where members left. We calculate the difference in `size` from the next value which changes and update `inds` position.

Comment: Perfect, this solves the issue. Thanks a lot, for the result and your explication!

Answer (score 1):

is this something your are looking for?

```
df %>% 
  arrange(team_id, year) %>% 
  mutate(diff = if_else((members> 0 & dplyr::lead(members, n=1)==0), size, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(team_id) %>% 
  mutate(diff = ifelse(diff>0, dplyr::last(size)-size, NA))
```

Comment: Almost. Seems I wasn't quite clear. Your approach calculates the difference between the  size at the time of members departure (correct) and the size at the latest point in time but I was looking for the difference between the size at the time of departure and the next (in year) different size. If the size doesn't change in the next year, then test the year after whether size changed, if this is not the case then test another year into the future etc. Thank you for your suggestion I am closer to the result now.